# How to enable multiple-user mode in windows 2003 enterprise edition?

Tags: windows

Currently there can be only one user logged in.

Comment: Also: you have 74 questions of which only about 30ish have accepted answers. You might want to consider accepting some to help us help you -- click the grey "tick" beside the answers that have helped you the most, then we all get some reputation "points". It's a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

By default you can have 2 remote users and one local console user. That's using the out-of-the-box setup - Terminal Services for Administration.

If you'd like to install a full TS system then you'll need to purchase CALs, Client Access Licenses.

What are you trying to do with your server? Generally, for admin, the 2+1 is fine. If you do want a full Terminal Services server, then in Administrative Tools (in Control Panel) you'll find the TS tools to switch modes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Alex's post, you have to have Remote Desktop enabled in the System Properties, under the Remote tab, same as you would in Windows XP.